# Golang Virtual Memory - heroku

Tags: heroku, go, virtual-memory

Using the Gorelic plugin, I've noticed that the virtual memory on my heroku dyno is steadily climbing even though the memory usage looks fine. The virtual memory never appears to exceed 1000M, but when it gets close I start to notice performance degradation.

I've used pprof to profile the memory usage of my app and it looks like it's free of leaks. Also, everything i've read suggests that Go will reserve large blocks of virtual memory and it's nothing to worry about.

Is it possible that the large virtual memory usage is affecting performance on my 1x heroku dyno? Is it just that I need to use 2x dynos because Go is a memory hog? Is it possible to configure go so that it uses less virtual memory?

Thanks!

Comment: Virtual memory shouldn't affect much. What does your app's RSS look like? If you're doing a lot of allocations, you may just be running out of processing power to keep up with GC in a little dyno.

Comment: runtime.ReadMemStats(ms) can tell you how long your program has spent doing GC. If that seems to be your problem, the best fix is to reduce the amount of allocations in your application, then to add cpu power, and then to wait for Go's GC to mature further

Comment: Also read this: https://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_does_my_Go_process_use_so_much_virtual_memory